# LaTeX with Edits

Tags: feature-request, bug, mathjax

Two questions:

1. Right after I edit one of my own questions and look at the rendered $\LaTeX$, it looks funny. Everything appears larger than normal and the math seems to be oversized or written in another font. I'm not sure if this happens with just mine, or with all edits / suggested edits that I am involved in. Exhibit A: Compare [image] with [image] Ironically, this was after editing *this* question: how meta of me.
2. Related to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/why-we-cant-see-suggested-edits-rendered-in-latex-before-approving) which got $5$ upvotes $0$ downvotes (not answered, and the comments suggested a "hack" solution but I think the feature would be nice): It would be very helpful to be able to see edits previewed in actual latex (as they would be seen) when considering "suggested edits." As it stands I have difficultly ascertaining what changes were made - I very nearly approved an edit with a bunch of one-space red highlights everywhere, and then I realized that the editor had just removed spaces with absolutely no change to the actual rendered text.

---

Exhibit B:

*Right after edit with enlarged mathematics:*

[image]

*After refresh back to normal:*

[image]

Those are screenshots, I apologize for the second pic being slightly grainy, I was having trouble with copying and pasting and it got distorted.

Comment: "I'm not sure if this happens with just mine" No, I have that too. I refresh and curse silently.

Comment: @DanielFischer So what happens now? Does this post just sit here? I guess I'm not really sure how meta works, or who is able/willing to fix bugs like this...

Comment: Happens to me too.